# PHP : How to get unique values between two objects

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

**Goal: Get values which are unique in $resultSecond**

So I have two objects.

$result and $resultSecond

I want to get values which  are unique to $resultSecond and are **NOT** in the $result.

I tried to use array_diff(). 
It did not work as they are objects. I think.

Below is the code by which I am getting the data.

```
$result = db_query("
SELECT entity_id FROM field_data_field_date
WHERE bundle='postit' AND field_date_value > ".$customvishaltime." ");

$resultSecond = db_query("
SELECT entity_id FROM field_data_field_days
WHERE bundle='postit' AND field_days_value > ".$customvishaltime." ");
```

As per drupal the return of db_query is a prepared statement object. I have no clue what this means.

Reference:

For db_query
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7

- Have made changes as requested.

Comment: Both of these lines appear to be **incredibly** obvious typos: `$result->>entity_id`,`$resultSecond>entity_id`, and you can't even attribute these obvious errors in code to a language barrier. Please invest at least a *little* time in your questions if you expect people to spend time answering them.

Comment: These are not typos. I have named them that way. As you can see in the code they fetch data from different tables.

Comment: @vishal, @meagar is referring to the fact that the code you've posted is a syntax error as the `->` is not correct on either line.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee  I have  made the changes . That part was not the code but I can see how it was taken as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off doing this as a left join query:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT q2.entity_id 
                    FROM (
                           SELECT entity_id FROM field_data_field_days
                           WHERE bundle='postit' AND field_days_value > %f
                          ) AS q2 LEFT JOIN (

                           SELECT entity_id FROM field_data_field_date
                           WHERE bundle='postit' AND field_date_value > %f

                      ) AS q1 ON q2.entity_id = q1.entity_id

                    WHERE q1.entity_id IS NULL", $customvishaltime, $customvishaltime);
```